# add rows of 2D arrays in processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a function to sum up the rows of 2D arrays. I already have the code, but the return value does not seem to be working. Just need your thoughts as I need this finished in 24 hours :D

```
int sumRows(int ArrayR[][]){
int row=3;
  int col=3;
  int sumR = ArrayR[0][0];
  //int [] sumR = new int[row];
  for (int i = 0; i<row; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<col; j++){
    sumR+=ArrayR[i][i];
    }
   }
  return sumR;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum the elements of a matrix, then there are 2 issues in your code:

You have to initialize `sumR` by *0*, else the element at index `[0][0]` would be added twice:

```
int sumR = 0;
```

Further you have 2 control variables `i` and `j` in the nested loop, but you use `i` for the column and the rows when you look up the matrix `ArrayR`.

Change

```
sumR+=ArrayR[i][i];
```

to

```
sumR+=ArrayR[i][j];
```

focus on `[i][j]`

But if you want to sum each row of a matrix, then you have to return an array of sums from the function and you have to store the sum of each row separately in an element of the array. You can do it like this:

```
int[] sumRows(int ArrayR[][]){

    int row = ArrayR.length;
    int[] sumR = new int[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){

        int col = ArrayR[i].length; 
        sumR[i] = 0;  
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            sumR[i] += ArrayR[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sumR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are suming all the number but inicializing with a non zero number. change it to:

```
int sumRows(int ArrayR[][]){
  int row=3;
  int col=3;
  int sumR = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<row; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<col; j++){
      sumR+=ArrayR[i][j];
    }
   }
  return sumR;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input! assuming that the 2D array is    int [][] Array2 = {{1,2,3},
                       {1,2,3},
                       {1,2,3}}; I'm lookine for a result like this {3,6,9} :D

Comment: i actually just did this instead int sumRows (int ArrayR[][]){
  int arrayr1 = 0;
  int arrayr2 = 0;
  int arrayr3 = 0;
    arrayr1 = ArrayR[0][0]+ArrayR[0][1]+ArrayR[0][2];
    arrayr2 = ArrayR[1][0]+ArrayR[1][1]+ArrayR[1][2];
    arrayr3 = ArrayR[2][0]+ArrayR[2][1]+ArrayR[2][2];
 return arrayr1;
 //return sumR;
}   i need to have an output sumR for all the sum of each row :D Appreciate your help!

Comment: ahhh ok I misunderstood you. @Rabbid76 answer will do the job